# How to maintain Iterator using Java

Tags: java, list, iterator

I Have Iterator instance. I have to get the size of this. Here I am getting the size of entries. Mean size is 8. Suppose I want to show only 5 values within this iterator. How can I implement this one?

```
Document<Feed> feeddoc = resp.getDocument();
List<Entry> entries = feeddoc.getRoot().getEntries();
entries = feeddoc.getRoot().getEntries();
Iterator<Entry> iterator = entries.iterator();
int size = entries.size();  //8

while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    /* here I am getting 8 values means iterating 8 times but I want to iterate only 5 times */
    Entry next = iterator.next();
    userDetailsVos = new UserDetailsVos();
    userDetailsVos.setTitle(next.getTitle());

    final IRI temp = next.getLinkResolvedHref("alternate");
    userDetailsVos.setUrl(temp.toString());
    userDetailsVos.setTime(next.getContentElement().getFirstChild().getElements().get(5).getText());

    System.out.println("(1)--" + next.getTitle());
    System.out.println("(2)--" + next.getContentElement().getFirstChild().getElements().get(5).getText());
    System.out.println("url: " + temp.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell the loop to iterate over at most 5 elements :

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 5 && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
         ....
```

This would iterate over at most 5 elements, but if there are less than 5, it would iterate only as long as the iterator has a next element.

Comment: Thanks...itz Working...@Eran

Answer (score 4):

You can use List#subLists

for example

```
entries.subList(0,4).iterator();
```

It will only give 0 to 4 th element of the List

Comment: entries.subList()- simple and best approach for these kind of criterias. No need of counters and explicit for loops!

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable like:

```
int count = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    if (count == 5) 
        break;
    count ++;
    //existing logic...
```